# Unreachable code, Switch, break. JSP - Java

Tags: java, jsp, switch-statement, break

I have this code, but I getting this message:

**Unreachable code** just in the first line with the **break** sentence

Here other example of **my code**:

```
public HTMLFile(Object... argv) {
  this.Name = (String)argv[0];
  switch( argv.length ) {
    case 6: //assigning the value 6th variable and follow with other variables
      this.StyleSheet = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\""+(String)argv[5]+"\" type=\"text/css\" />";
    case 5://assigning the value 5th variable and follow with other variables
      this.ShortCutIcon = "<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\""+(String)argv[4]+"\" type=\"image/x-icon\" />";
    case 4:
      this.css = (CSS)argv[3];
    case 3:
      this.HtmlMeta = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; "+this.CharSet[(Integer)argv[2]]+"\" />";
      this.HtmlTitle = "<title>"+(String)argv[1]+"</title>";
      break;
    case 2:
      this.HtmlTitle = "<title>"+(String)argv[1]+"</title>";
      this.HtmlMeta = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; "+this.CharSet[0]+"\" />";
      break;
    case 1:
      this.HtmlTitle = "<title></title>";
      this.HtmlMeta = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; "+this.CharSet[0]+"\" />";
      break;
   }
  this.ResetFile();
}
```

And the error:

```
Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 76 en el archivo jsp: /WorkingDB/HTML.jsp
Unreachable code
73:         case 3:
74:           this.HtmlMeta = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;     "+this.CharSet[(Integer)argv[2]]+"\" />";
75:           this.HtmlTitle = "<title>"+(String)argv[1]+"</title>";
76:           break;
77:         case 2:
78:           this.HtmlTitle = "<title>"+(String)argv[1]+"</title>";
79:           this.HtmlMeta = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; "+this.CharSet[0]+"\" />";
```

Similar error **again** in real code:

```
HTMLForm(String Name, String Form, int Method, Object... argv) {
  this.Name = Name;
  this.Form = Form;
  this.Method = Method;
  switch( argv.length ) {
    case 1:
      this.css = (CSS)argv[0];
      break;
    case 2:
      this.css = (CSS)argv[0];
      this.Action = (String)argv[1];
      break;
  }
}
```

The message error again:

```
Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 825 en el archivo jsp: /WorkingDB/HTML.jsp
Unreachable code
822:       switch( argv.length ) {
823:         case 1:
824:           this.css = (CSS)argv[0];
825:           break;
826:         case 2:
827:           this.css = (CSS)argv[0];
828:           this.Action = (String)argv[1];
```

Maybe it's a foolish question, but I can't get the mistake.

```
C:\Users\PC>java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\PC>
```

Tomcat Version: Tomcat 7.0.19

Comment: Didn't you accidentally wrote `switch(sSpc.length)` instead of `switch(argv.length)`. The Java compiler will normally try to do constant propagation...

Comment: Interesting, I'm not getting the error even using sSpc.length, but I agree that there might be some differences between the provided code and the actual one.

Comment: argv.length is the length of variable argument of the method...

Comment: Just an observation: in the second sample the error happens on the first block with `break`.  What is your `Java EE` version? Do you use compiler from SDK, IDE (like Eclipse), or something else?

Comment: Please provide the /actual/ code that produces the problem you're describing.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7.0.19, JDK 1.7.0_17
I'm not using eclipse.
The code is shown in the question, because the error message indicates the line 76: just above is shown the real code.

Comment: `java` is not a compiler, `javac` is. What's your version?  Or do you use something else for compiling?

Comment: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_17

Comment: So.. this is a runtime error.. Then the unreachable error is not the usual in compile time, can you show your: /WorkingDB/HTML.jsp? Can you debug argv.length before the switch?

Comment: Well, in my case, it's caused by two return statements at the end of a function (I forgot to delete the last one after editing), and the error points to another return statement at the beginning (in a if statement).

Comment: My bug report against Tomcat 7.0.x: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58110